# Ionic 2 Pipe requires data from database - how is this possible?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, pipe, ionic2

I am trying to use a custom pipe in Angular 2 for my Ionic 2 (RC 2) project but I can not work out how it should be written. My biggest issue is that the pipe relies on data from the database to determine whether the filter should return true or false.

**newsData array:**

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "softwareName": 0,
    "categoryName": 0,
    "title": "Notification Title",
    "description": "Shoft description for notifications",
    "date": "2016-01-05 16:23:23"
  }
]
```

**Settings JSON returned by getCategoriesForAllSoftware():**

```
[
    {
        categories: [
            {
                categoryId: 0,
                categoryName: "category1",
                onOffState: 1
            },
            {
                ...
            }
        ],
        onOffState: 1,
        softwareId: 0,
        softwareName: "software1"
    },  
    {
        ...
    }
]
```

**Here is the code for my pipe:**

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform}               from '@angular/core';
import {Platform}                          from 'ionic-angular';
import {DatabaseService}                   from '../providers/database/init';
import {GlobalFunctions}                   from '../providers/globalFunctions';

@Pipe({name: 'notificationSettings'})
export class NotificationSettingsPipe implements PipeTransform {

constructor(
    public databaseService: DatabaseService,
    public globalFunctions: GlobalFunctions,
    public platform: Platform
) {}

transform(cards: Array<Object>) {
    this.platform.ready().then((readySource) => {
        return this.databaseService.getCategoriesForAllSoftware().then((data) => {
            var softwareCategoryStates = this.globalFunctions.generateSoftwareCategoriesArray(data);
            return cards.filter((card) => this.cardFilter(card, softwareCategoryStates));
        }, (error) => {
            console.error("Error in Pipe: ", error);
        });
    });
}

cardFilter(card, softwareNots) {
    var flag = true;
    for (var i=0; i<softwareNots.length; i++) {
        if (card.softwareName == softwareNots[i]['softwareName']) {
            console.debug("SOFTWARENOTS[I]", softwareNots[i]);
            if (softwareNots[i]['onOffState'] == 0) {
                flag = false;
            } else {
                var notificationTypes = softwareNots[i]['categories'];
                for (var j=0; j<notificationTypes.length; j++) {
                    if (card.categoryName == notificationTypes[j]['categoryName']) {
                        console.debug("NOTIFICATIONTYPES[J]", notificationTypes[j]);
                        if (notificationTypes[j]['onOffState'] == 0) {
                            flag = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
}
```

**This is the code that should display the filtered list items in my view file**

```
<div *ngFor="let card of (newsData | notificationSettings)">
  <ion-card>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-icon name="{{card.icon}}" item-right></ion-icon>
      <ion-avatar item-left>
        <p class="product {{card.softwareName}}"></p>
      </ion-avatar>
      <h2>{{card.title}}</h2>
      <p class="publish-date">{{card.date | date:'d MMM'}}</p>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-card>
</div>
```

In the code above, I expect the newsData item to display in my ion-list because the settings JSON has the onOffState set to 1 for both software and category. Currently however, nothing from my array is displaying on the front end.

I may be going the wrong way about trying to access the information from the database however my issue seems to be trying to use the filter after the platform is ready and the database has returned the JSON data.

Comment: Are you expecting that to change frequently? It might be easier to access the database in the component and make the pipe pure by passing `softwareCategoryStates ` into it. Also, you haven't said what happens in the code you've posted.

Comment: I had tried passing in the database JSON as a parameter of the pipe but I seemed to be struggling with the pipe trying to evaluate the *ngFor iterator before the database had finished gathering and returning the data. Should the *ngFor filter update itself when the database object parameter is updated?

Comment: Is `newsData` also coming from an observable? In that case, use e.g. [`forkJoin`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/forkjoin.md) to run the two in parallel and gather both sets of results - then you can set `newsData` for the `*ngFor` at a time when you know you also have whatever you're getting from the database.

Comment: I am not using the Observable class in my code. Would this help then?

Comment: Oh right. Could you give some more context around what you're doing? Where is the data you're looping over coming from? Please [edit] to give more of a [mcve].

Comment: I have updated the question with the format of the newsData array and the results that I am currently seeing from this code.

Comment: That's still not a good example - could you show a minimal example of the component and any related services, not just the pipe and the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement an async pipe

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html#!#async-pipe

An async pipe will accomodate the delay in getting the data from the db.

Comment: Do you have any rough examples of how to write the code using async pipes? I am struggling to understand the syntax and how they should be written.

Comment: no sorry, not had the need to write one in Angular2 yet

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my issue but I did so by changing the database query, NOT by using a pipe. Unfortunately that does not resolve the issue that I raised but I have found a workaround which does the job I needed it to.

My database query now uses the WHERE clause to filter out the data that I did not want to display.